# Why is this Line Coming Across My UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uicolor

I have a UISearch Bar with a few Placeholders. I'm making a simple search app for learning iOS, so I'm really new. I found that there was a weird line that was coming behind my UISearchBar whenever I started editing it as in the image : [image]

My SearchBar code is pretty much the standard as any other search bar. I've tried doing the following, but they haven't worked :

```
//    [self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//    self.searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;

//    searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
//    searchBar.layer.borderColor = self.searchBar.layer.borderColor;
//    CGRect maskingLine = self.searchBar.frame;
//    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(maskingLine.origin.x, maskingLine.origin.y+20, maskingLine.size.width, 10)];
//    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//    [self.searchBar addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: Please provide the full screen print.

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding a subview to the search bar?

Comment: That's something I tried. But it didn't work. Tried to mask the line.

Comment: remove you lineView that you are subview on the searchBar

Comment: The commented is code is stuff that I have tried to solve the problem! It is not the code causing the problem. Is it not clear? Not what I am doing!

Comment: Can someone please click on the damn close button so I can close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding (for some unknown reason) a subview called `lineView` to the search bar. That line you are seeing is the `lineView`.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be it. The lineView has a height of 10.

Comment: And you are moving it's origin down 20 pts with maskingLine.origin.y+20, so it seems that line is the top of the view.  It would help if you could see the more of the screen.